# Magmi will not update images

Tags: import, magmi

Im using the datapump API - it works fine with my products, but now with updating images it wont work.

This is my array that Magmi doesnt like

```
array(8) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(6) "simple"
  ["sku"]=>
  string(6) "131017"
  ["image"]=>
  string(73) "/media/sdc3/wwwroot/site/public/importer/../import/NO/A_131017.jpg"
  ["small_image"]=>
  string(73) "/media/sdc3/wwwroot/site/public/importer/../import/NO/A_131017.jpg"
  ["thumbnail"]=>
  string(73) "/media/sdc3/wwwroot/site/public/importer/../import/NO/A_131017.jpg"
  ["image_label"]=>
  string(8) "A_131017"
  ["small_image_label"]=>
  string(8) "A_131017"
  ["thumbnail_label"]=>
  string(8) "A_131017"
}
```

(the path to the images are correct, and working)

When I imported my products, this worked fine, but there were descriptions etc. on

I have the following magmi settings:

using mode - *Update existing items only,skip new ones*
Image import mode - *override existing images*
Pre-download check for remote images - *enabled*
Assign only existing images - *no*

My profile is also correct

Comment: If you found an answer please share it and mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1):

image import is done relatively to image plugin "read local images from" field.
i would advise to put:

```
/media/sdc3/wwwroot/site/public/importer/../import/
```

in this plugin configuration field.

Then to put only relative path in the datapump:

```
["image"]=>"NO/A_131017.jpg"
```

This is due to magmi compatibility with legacy dataflow format where "relative" paths were beginning with / , so magmi removes the first / from the value and considers all images as relative to something.

More complex setup is:
having defined "magento base path" with a path (say /where/is/magento)
having defined "real local images from" of image plugin to a relative path (relative/images)
then put a value in the data for image (/false/relative/for/images/myimage.jpg)

Then the path that magmi would take for images would be:

```
/where/is/magento/relative/images/false/relative/for/images/myimage.jpg
```

Comment: Yea, I also read that part - but what I found very strange is its actually working fine in my full import (where I import both images, descriptions and other variables). But apparently it does not work when I only add image.

The problem is that Im uploading the images in a not web folder, and I will not just move the files to media/import because I need to see which images that does gets imported.

And as I can see its not possible to get a list of which SKU that got imported in magmi.

Comment: what version are you using ?

Comment: That would be _RELEASE NOTES FOR MAGMI 0.7.18beta1_ taken from the release notes file, and the plugins were also downloaded at the same time

Comment: may you try the latest (0.7.18 , no beta) & latest plugins ?

Comment: Well, i ditched magmi for just updating images, and instead used Magento product model, actually its not slow at all for this one purpose.

I still use Magmi for the data import and also images, but not Magmi just for images

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the magmi  setting you need to assign the directory of images in magmi setting area no  need to assign to particular images. 
magmi  automatically pick the location make sure see the permission of folder also.

> please follow the steps on below link.

```
https://www.phpro.be/news/magmi-magento-mass-importer
```